# Need help regarding attacking a thread leak issue

Tags: multithreading, profiling, threadpool

So we have created a new Netty4 server and are generating load against it. The number of host threads is growing as a function of the TPS to the server. Moreover once the load test is over, the host thread count is not going down (suggesting there is a thread leak of some kind).

I took an hprof dump using jstack and hooked it up to JProfiler. In the thread view the lions share of the threads are of the format. (Note this is a thread dump hours after the load test and is one instance of it, there are thousands of these being stuck in ).

Thread dump at 26013:42.622.361

```
Thread group "main":

Thread "I/O dispatcher 18120":
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(long, int, long, int)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(long) (line: 269)
at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(long) (line: 93)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(long) (line: 86)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(long) (line: 97)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute() (line: 255)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(org.apache.http.nio.reactor.IOEventDispatch) (line: 104) at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run() (line: 588 at java.lang.Thread.run() (line: 748)
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here further (for instance I have no idea what executor service IO dispatcher is supposed to reference).

This question is for general guidance on how to attack thread leak problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the IO thread dispatcher is part of the Apache HTTP client.

We had to keep a cache of apache http clients (to be more pedantic, aws elastic search clients since they are setup per request credentials https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-configuration-samples.html). Anytime we saw a new request we acquired from the client from this cache.

Now our load test was throwing many requests with different credentials. The cache kept getting larger and larger faster than the clients expired from the cache. Each client used up more and more threads until we ran out of them.